# How to fit a small QR code to a big canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to create an image of a QR code using canvas that will look like:

[image]

In order to generate the QR code I use the [qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode) module.
I tried to start with a big canvas (325,600) and then add the QR code to it (width=325) but it looks like it modifies the canvas dimensions to fit the QR code dimensions so the resulted image is 325x325:
[image: fitted qr code]

This is the code I used in order to do it:

```js
const qrCode = require('qrcode');
const canvas = createCanvas(325, 600);

qrCode.toCanvas(canvas, link, {
  width: 325,
  margin: 14
}, error => {
  if(error)
    return reject(error);
});
```

My second approach was to resize the canvas **after** adding the QR code to it but then the QR code disappeared from the image:

[image: qr code gone]

This is the code I used:

```js
const qrCode = require('qrcode');
const canvas = createCanvas(325, 325);

qrCode.toCanvas(canvas, link, {
  width: 325,
  margin: 14
}, error => {
  if(error)
    return reject(error);
});

canvas.height = 600;
```

How do I implement it?

Comment: What do you need the space above the QR code for? Could you implement that with padding/margin around the canvas element?

Comment: @chazsolo thanks for the reply. I need it for text..the idea is to have a title for the qr code. The title can be long so it needs to be wrapped and the canvas height should grow in accordance with the number of lines the wrapped title has